# Ruby/Rails hash to XML: what's the key for XML path that has no value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have to make XML that follows this format:

```
    <Address>
        <AddressLine1>ADDRESS LINE</AddressLine1> 
        <City>CITY</City> 
        <StateProvinceCode>XX</StateProvinceCode> 
        <CountryCode>YY</CountryCode> 
        <PostalCode>00000</PostalCode> 
        <ResidentialAddress /> #<-- what do I do for this one?
    </Address>
```

I'm going to make a ruby hash with my values and run `.to_xml` on it. However, I noticed that the `ResidentialAddress` doesn't have a closing tag, and also that there are no values for that. How would I add that in my ruby hash?

Answer (score 0):

XML defines `<ResidentialAddress />` as identical to `<ResidentialAddress></ResidentialAddress>`. Both are well-defined to have contents of "null" (in your language), NOT `''`, an empty string.